# Not getting all data from API

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

```
let APIUrl = NSURL(string:"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)&lon=(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)&appid=e7b2054dc37b1f464d912c00dd309595&units=Metric%22")
    let request = URLRequest(url:APIUrl! as URL)
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            print(error ?? "Error is empty.")
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse ?? "HTTP response is empty.")
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        do {
            let weatherData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyWeather.self, from: responseData)
            let ggtemp = weatherData.main?.temp
            print(ggtemp!, "THIS IS THE TEMP")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tempDisplay.text = String(format: "%.1f", ggtemp!)
            }
        } catch  {
            print("error parsing response from POST on /todos")
            return
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

I want to get the temperature of my current Location.
Here is what I get when app runs:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x28322fbe0> { URL: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)&lon=(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)&appid=e7b2054dc37b1f464d912c00dd309595&units=Metric%22 } { Status Code: 400, Headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" =     (
        true
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" =     (
        "GET, POST"
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
        "*"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        78
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sun, 21 Oct 2018 09:57:38 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        openresty
    );
    "X-Cache-Key" =     (
        "/data/2.5/weather?lat=&lon=&units=Metric%22"
    );
} }
error parsing response from POST on /todos
```

Any ideas on how to get the temp from this API?

Here is my struct code:

```
   struct Coordinate : Decodable {
    let lat, lon : Double?
}

struct Weather : Decodable {
    var id : Int?
    var main, myDescription, icon : String?

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case main = "main"
        case icon = "icon"
        case myDescription = "description"
    }
}

struct Sys : Decodable {
    let type, id : Int?
    let sunrise, sunset : Date?
    let message : Double?
    let country : String?
}

struct Main : Decodable {
    let temp : Double?
}

struct MyWeather : Decodable {
    let coord : Coordinate?
    let cod, visibility, id : Int?
    let name : String?
    let base : String?
    let weather : [Weather]?
    let sys : Sys?
    let main : Main?
    let dt : Date?

}
```

Comment: You are shooting yourself in the foot with this line: `print("error parsing response from POST on /todos")` You are receiving a lovely and valuable error message and you are just throwing it away! Instead, say `print(error)`. You will learn exactly what the problem is (and so will we).

Comment: Thanks Matt. I updated the print(error).  The original error went away, but I am still not getting the temperature that I want.

Comment: Yes but you’re missing the point. What’s the error???

Comment: Also please show the JSON we’re trying to parse.

Comment: I probably need to slow down and pay more attention to JSON Parsing. I don't have that yet!

Comment: your code works for me. What error are you getting now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check your api in postman get this response

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 90.36,
        "lat": 23.79
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 721,
            "main": "Haze",
            "description": "haze",
            "icon": "50d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 304.15,
        "pressure": 1013,
        "humidity": 62,
        "temp_min": 304.15,
        "temp_max": 304.15
    },
    "visibility": 3000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 4.1,
        "deg": 330
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 20
    },
    "dt": 1540182600,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 7879,
        "message": 0.0056,
        "country": "BD",
        "sunrise": 1540166342,
        "sunset": 1540207601
    },
    "id": 1337178,
    "name": "Dhaka District",
    "cod": 200
}
```

this is your full API response model class used this code

```
   struct MyWeather : Decodable {
    let coord : Coordinate?
    let weather : [Weather]?
    let base : String?
    let main : Main?
    let visibility: Int?
    let wind : Wind?
    let clouds : Clouds?
    let dt : Date?
    let sys : Sys?
    let id : Int?
    let name : String?
    let cod : Int?
}

struct Coordinate : Decodable {
    let lat : Double?
    let lon : Double?
}

struct Weather : Decodable {
    var id : Int?
    var main, myDescription, icon : String?

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case main = "main"
        case icon = "icon"
        case myDescription = "description"
    }

}

struct Main : Decodable {
    let temp : Double?
    let pressure : Int?
    let humidity : Int?
    let temp_min : Double?
    let temp_max : Double?
}

struct Wind : Decodable {
    let speed : Double?
    let deg : Int?
}

struct Clouds: Decodable {
    let all : Int?
}

struct Sys : Decodable {
    let type : Int?
    let id : Int?
    let message : Double?
    let country : String?
    let sunrise : Date?
    let sunset : Date?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is parsing the data. However, I noticed at the end of your URL **units=Metric%22** which should just be **units=Metric**. Also, your lat and lon will be incorrect. **lat=(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)** should be **lat=\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)** and same for lon.

Comment: This helped greatly.